Selenium Webdriver: How to click IMG element using xPath
I'm trying hard to click this button but it always gives me the NoSuchElement error.
<div class="col-3 col-sm-2 text-right d-flex align-items-center">
    <img src="https://cdn-ltm.betflag.it/site/img/close.svg" id="ButtonClose" class="img-fluid" onclick="preCloseSigup()" style="display: inline;">
</div>

Method code:
def press_button(xpath):
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        driver.find_element("xpath", xpath).click()
    except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException):
         pass

Code
press_button("//div[@class='col-3 col-sm-2 text-right d-flex align-items-center']//svg")

or
press_button("//*[@id='ButtonClose']")

I've tried different XPaths and I've also tried building them by reading what's written on the forum but nothing.

To get correct XPath you can right-click on the button you want, then click on Inspect, then on selected row again right-click, then go Copy, and then "Copy XPath" or "Copy full XPath", then you can compare what you are missing. Per me find_element_by_id will be easier: driver.find_element_by_id(_id).click() you will need to pass id instead, i.e. ButtonClose.

My guess is that the element is in an IFRAME or shadow-root. Can you share a link to the page?

@Vardan Grigoryants thanks for your answers but, I tried to click the button using “By.ID” but no luck, it does not exist for selenium.

@JeffC The site is 'https://www.betflag.it/sport'. You have to click 'Registrati' in green in the upper right corner. The button in question is the red one in the upper right corner

@Gabriele It's weird... that site is blocked for me. Anyway... it looks like my suggestion about looking for IFRAMEs paid off and you found a solution.

Eventually I was able to solve it by better analyzing the HTML code. It was all contained inside a frame, so I used this:
def tryto_exit_from_signup(driver, timeout=5):
    try:
        frame_signeup = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "IframeSignup")))
        driver.switch_to.frame(frame_signeup)
        press_button(driver, "By.ID", "ButtonClose")
        press_button(driver, "By.ID", "Button5")
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

the except TimeoutException is put on purpose, since the alert does not always appear, so in case it appears at the beginning it removes it, otherwise it executes the 'pass' after 5 seconds

Be careful when posting code that you don't turn regular single ' or double " quotes into "curly" quotes, e.g. “”. Those will not be recognized by your IDE or compiler as actual quotes. I fixed your answer.

Your first XPath is not correct. It ends in "//svg" which does not match the element that you said you wanted to click in your question. This could be one reason it's not working but it's hard to tell with the limited info you provided.
Some suggestions...

Don't use time.sleep(). It's considered a "dumb" wait in that it always waits the same amount of time... if the element is ready earlier, it still waits X seconds. If the element isn't ready yet, it stops waiting anyway. Instead use WebDriverWait. There especially should be no need to wait a second and THEN use a WebDriverWait. If the wait time is not long enough, then add a second to the WebDriverWait timeout after removing the sleep.

WebDriverWait.until() returns the waited on element, e.g.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
e = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(...))

or
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(...)).click()


Don't catch exceptions you aren't going to handle. Right now you are catching three exception types but not doing anything with them which means that if one of those exceptions are thrown, your script eats them and moves on which is going to cause the next line in your script to fail for some unknown reason.

A nitpick but naming is important... name your methods based on what they do. IMO, press_button() should be click_button() or better yet, click_element() because it's clicking (that's what Selenium call the action) ANY element passed in, not just BUTTON HTML tags.

Don't pass in an XPath string as a parameter. It limits your method to only using XPaths. Instead pass in a By locator... then you can use By.ID(),
By.CSS_SELECTOR(), and so on making your method way more flexible, e.g.

Use the proper EC method based on what action you are going to take on the element. If you are going to click an element, use EC.element_to_be_clickable(). If you are going to otherwise interact with the element, e.g. use .text or .send_keys(), then use EC.visibility_of_element_located().


With all this in mind, your method can be simplified to
def click_element(locator):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).click()

and can be called using
click_element((By.ID, "ButtonClose"))


Gabriele, I saw your answer. There's an EC for IFRAMEs that's easier to use, e.g.
frame_signeup = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "IframeSignup")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_signeup)

can be updated to
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "IframeSignup")))


If this still doesn't work, then it's likely that the element you are trying to click either isn't uniquely identified on the page by the locator, it's inside an IFRAME, or it's inside a shadow-root. We won't be able to tell without the URL or more info from you.

Thank you very much for your advice. I had to implement 'StaleElementReferenceException' among the exceptions because of the fast moving buttons on the page. (I inserted to retry at least 3 times with a smaller timeout, removing the time.sleep as you reported). Also, from the other buttons I have using the other locators mentioned by selenium, thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, the command you mentioned (click_element((By.ID, “ButtonClose”))) does not work

@Gabriele I saw your answer, I put a comment in my answer about an easier way to switch IFRAMEs using EC.
